# Storing a huge array of strings into IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexeddb

I have a huge array called `newCombs` when I call `store.put(game)` the tab turns white and is gone in chrome task manager. Basically the process just stops and it fails to store the array

```
var trans = this.db.transaction('Games', 'readwrite');
var store = trans.objectStore('Games');
store.get(new Date().toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + prize.value).onsuccess = function() {
  var game = this.result;
  game.combs = game.combs.concat(newCombs); //I'm appending to the game.combs array which is empty when I first run it (when it also crashes)
  store.put(game);
}
trans.oncomplete = function(evt) {
  arrLength = 0;
  newCombs = [];
}
```

This is what `game` is equal to:

```
game = {
   name: new Date().toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + prize.value,
   date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
   prize: prize.value,
   playerData: [...],
   points: {...}
}
```

The above part is a method of an object so `this` is not the window object everything works fine until the code hits the line with: `store.put(game);` the page just crashes.

Comment: Are you sure `this` is what you think it is? `this` is not preserved inside anonymous functions and you're using it inside an anonymous function in the `onsuccess` event handler. Did you try logging the `game` variable?

Comment: @paldepind `this` is correct in it's context it works fine I get the correct `game` object. Read the comment (just in case you ever get this problem) on the bottom I figured out my problem, I don't want to copy paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

As @paldepind suggests you are changing scope in the onsuccess event handler and losing sight of your custom object.

One way around this would be to take advantage of a closure and assign `this` to a local variable, before you define the anonymous callback function:

```
var trans = this.db.transaction('Games', 'readwrite');
var store = trans.objectStore('Games');
var that = this;
store.get(new Date().toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + prize.value).onsuccess =     function() {
  var game = that.result;
  game.combs = game.combs.concat(newCombs); 
  store.put(game);
}
trans.oncomplete = function(evt) {
  arrLength = 0;
  newCombs = [];
}
```

Comment: `this.result` gives me the correct object. The this method on the first line is just part of my main object. I'm only showing a certain method. It's not the `this` that's a problem. Btw thanks I figured out what the problem was. Concat is just slow one I'm making a new array with concat that's combining with `newCombs`. and then replacing the existing array of `game.combs`. Also `indexedDB` is for handling huge amounts of data but not at a time.

Comment: Of course, sorry - the result is from your get, wrong end of stick ! I've found indexedDB with lots of smaller transactions. Good luck :)